# Spring Roo Finder for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-roo

Can I create finder using roo with mongodb? 
It doesn't seem to support but I can't find anywhere says so.

I got the error/info : Command 'find list' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)

So the question is how can I create my own finder? all the example that I find on the net is for relational database and can't find one for mongodb.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how to create your own finders in the [Query Methods section of the Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html#mongodb.repositories.queries).

In Spring Roo with mongodb setup, your Repository interface already extends PagingAndSortingRepository.

If you have a model Person, with a property "lastName", you can declare a method findByLastname(String lastname) in your Repository interface. E.g.

```
@RooMongoRepository(domainType = Person.class)
public interface PersonRepository {
    List<Person> findAll();
    List<Person> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

For how to create other finders have a look at "**Table 6.1. Supported keywords for query methods**" in the link given above.